# Q: Android - How to start one activity from another without button click

Tags: java, android

If I have a rectangle in main activity which goes from left to right(using simple thread) until it touches the end of the screen, how can I make main activity switch to another activity when collision happens?
Edit:Added code for activity.I have method in "zmija" which checks for collision.

Main Activity

```
ZmijicaSV zmija;
private static int score=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    zmija=new ZmijicaSV(this);
    zmija.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(zmija);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zmija.pause();
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    zmija.resume();

}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean up=zmija.sp.isUp();
    boolean right=zmija.sp.isRight();
    boolean down=zmija.sp.isDown();
    boolean left=zmija.sp.isLeft();


    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if(up) {
                zmija.sp.setUp(false);
                zmija.sp.setRight(true);
                increaseScore();
                break;
            }

            if(right) {
                zmija.sp.setRight(false);
                zmija.sp.setDown(true);
                increaseScore();
                break;
            }

            if(down) {
                zmija.sp.setDown(false);
                zmija.sp.setLeft(true);
                increaseScore();
                break;
            }
            if(left) {
                zmija.sp.setLeft(false);
                zmija.sp.setUp(true);
                increaseScore();
            break;
        }


    }
        return true;
    }

public void increaseScore()
{
    score++;

}
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}
public void setScore(int s)
{
    score=s;
}

public boolean Collision()
{
    if(zmija.checkCollision())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

If you're calling it from a surface view

```
if(collision) 
startActivity(new Intent(context, GameOver.class));
```

Where context is the context is the Context you have used to create your surface view.

If you are calling an activity from within an activity, you can call it like so:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Comment: I added the code.Where in my main activity should I call it?Is it possible to call that startActivity in non activity class?

Comment: public boolean Collision()
    {
        if(zmija.checkCollision())
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

I forgot to add this method to main activity.If the result of method is "true" where to call start activity?

Comment: I will thanks for tips!I hope you can still help me out on this...been looking for answers for 2  days without any luck.

Comment: I have another class ZmijicaSV which uses SurfaceView...I have collision detection method there.I'm using that one in my main activity with zmijica.checkCollsion();